# siunitx : do not align on parentheses

Tags: siunitx

I want to create a `siunitx` column type which dot-aligns numeric values. These values can be wrapped in parentheses or not. If there are parentheses, they should be printed tightly around the number; not aligned.

In the latest version of `siunitx`, the `table-align-text-pre` and `table-align-text-post` have been deprecated in favor of the `table-align-text-before` and `table-align-text-after` functions.

In previous versions, I could compile this document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[
  input-open-uncertainty=,
  input-close-uncertainty=,
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false
]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d}
  -10.10048\\
  (2.123)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and obtain this tabular result:

[image]

With the latest version of `siunitx`, I obtain this result instead, regardless of whether I use `pre/before` or `post/after`:

[image]

Two questions:

1. How can I create a column type which displays parentheses tightly around the number (first image)?
2. Is there a way to achieve this result that is independent of `siunitx` versions? (Or that works with versions released in the last couple years.)

Desiderata:

- A solution that does not rely on `parse-numbers=false`.
- A solution that does not require me to specify ex ante the width of each column

I read [section "9.7 Regression tables" of the manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en), but the author still uses `table-align-text-pre` and the minimal document I pasted above does not produce the expected outcome.

Comment: I'll see if there's an issue here at the design level

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/526: I'll try to fix over the next couple of days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you've encountered vanishes automatically if you replace all four current options, *viz.*,

```
  input-open-uncertainty=,
  input-close-uncertainty=,
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false
```

with the single option

```
  input-symbols = ()
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[input-symbols = ()]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d}
  -10.10048\\
   (2.123)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Answer tested with version 2021-08-04 v3.0.24 of `siunitx` package.

Comment: Looks like this also works on version 2.8b. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Incorporate the parentheses in `table-format`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[
  input-open-uncertainty=,
  input-close-uncertainty=,
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false, table-format=(-2.5)
]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{d}
  -10.10048\\
  (2.123)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! It looks great with the most recent version, but unfortunately fails to compile on version 2.8b, which is barely over a year old: `Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '(-2.5)'.`

Comment: It was intended to work with version 3. Perhaps with option `input-digits=0123456789()`? There was something like that in previous versions, but as I don't have any more the previous documentation, I can't check the details.

Comment: I realize it's unfair to request a solution that works across versions. Thanks for your useful answer! (FWIW, I couldn't immediately make `input-digits` but I'll keep trying.)

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact key name, but it consists in adding symbols to the normal digits.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in `siunitx` which will be fixed in upcoming v3.0.25. The change can be applied as a patch using

```latex
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_center_marker:
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
      { \ensuremath { \mathord { \l_siunitx_number_output_decimal_tl } } }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF
      { \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_integer_box }
        >
          {
              \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
            - \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
          }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l__siunitx_table_align_after_bool
          {
            \__siunitx_table_center_marker_aux:Nnnn \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
              {
                  \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_integer_box
                + \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
              }
           }
           {
             \__siunitx_table_center_marker_aux:Nnnn \l__siunitx_table_after_box
               {
                   \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_after_box
                 + \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_integer_box
                 - \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
                 + \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
               }
           }
               { } { \__siunitx_table_fil: }
      }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l__siunitx_table_align_before_bool
          {
            \__siunitx_table_center_marker_aux:Nnnn \l__siunitx_table_integer_box
              {
                  \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
                - \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
              }
          }
          {
            \__siunitx_table_center_marker_aux:Nnnn \l__siunitx_table_before_box
               {
                   \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_before_box
                 + \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
                 - \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_integer_box
                 - \box_wd:N \l__siunitx_table_tmp_box
               }
          }
              { \__siunitx_table_fil: } { }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_center_marker_aux:Nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn #1 {#2}
      {
        #3
        \hbox_unpack:N #1
        #4
      }
  }
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_direct_marker_end:
  {
      \c_math_toggle_token
    \hbox_set_end:
    \bool_set_true:N \l__siunitx_table_align_before_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l__siunitx_table_align_after_bool
    \__siunitx_table_center_marker:
    \use:c { __siunitx_table_align_ \l__siunitx_table_align_text_tl :n }
      {
        \box_use_drop:N \l__siunitx_table_integer_box
        \box_use_drop:N \l__siunitx_table_decimal_box
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, for the amazing turnaround, and for the great package! Just to confirm, `table-align-text-pre` is *not* expected to keep working in the future, but `-before` is? (I'm using this in software that generates LaTeX code so I'd like to maximize the range of supported version numbers in case users don't have the latest version installed.)

Comment: @Vincent Well I've deprecated `text-align-text-pre`, but there will be no removals from v3.x of any deprecated names. So it will be working for ever as far as I am concerned, but I would use `text-align-text-before` for new material.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, much appreciated!