# siunitx error processing parentheses and negative signs after 3.0.25 update

Tags: tables, siunitx

Today I installed the latest version of MiKTeX in a new windows computer and attempted to run the following siunitx code in the preamble, which, among other things, helps me format my tables such that the alignment ignores stars, negative signs, and parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=large}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
        \usepackage{siunitx} 
        \sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4,
                detect-mode,
                tight-spacing           = true,
                input-signs             = ,
                input-symbols           = ,
                input-open-uncertainty  = ,
                input-close-uncertainty = ,
                table-align-text-pre    = false,
                table-space-text-pre    = (,
                } % centering in tables
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l *{1}{S[table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post =***]}} \toprule \toprule
    &       \mc{(1)}        \\
    &       \mc{OLS}        \\ 
    \midrule \\
    ABC & -0.003*** \\
    & ( 0.001) \\ \addlinespace
    Constant &  0.006*** \\
    & ( 0.001) \\
    Observations & \mc{60,571}  \\
    RMSE & \mc{ 0.071} \\
    \bottomrule \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I got no error messages after running this code, but the alignment is off and the opening parentheses and negative signs overlap with numbers. See below for an example:

[image: Sample output with error]

By calling a previous version of siunitx, I got it to work as desired. See the code and output below:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}[=2021-04-09]
```

[image: Sample output without error]

Could anyone please help me understand what might be happening with my code after the update and how to fix it such that I do not need to call the previous siunitx version?

Thank you!

Comment: you should always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a side-effect of the bug fix that happened for this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610213/siunitx-do-not-align-on-parentheses

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Example added, thanks!

Comment: the example is incomplete. But beside this: your table format is wrong, you have a negative number, so it should be `table-format=-1.3`.

Comment: @DonHosek I tried @Mico 's solution of adding `input-symbols = ()` instead of `input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
        table-space-text-pre    = (` but that did not help either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, I was missing the closing of the table and document. I appreciate your input! Nonetheless, adding the negative to the `table-format` does not make a difference in the output for neither the previous nor the new version of siunitx in my case. Please see the second picture.

Comment: Please log an issue for `siunitx`: I must have missed something

Comment: @JosephWright it looks ok for me if I correct the table-format (but `table-format=(1.3` is better than `table-format=-1.3` as in text mode the parens is larger). I checked in texlive and miktex.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for looking into this (and for the great work with siunitx!), but @UlrikeFischer 's suggestion was right in the end (I will be using `table-format=(1.3`). Many thanks for your helpful comments, Ulrike.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes but it worked in v2 without that, so I must have missed _something_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the v2 to v3 changes is that `table-format` now 'knows' about pre/post text. However, that does mean that here you need to include the pre-text in the `table-format`, otherwise your `table-space-text-pre = (` gets 'lost'. So using `table-format = (1.3` should do it.